# PHP total order

Tags: php, subtotal, webstore

I have a site that displays items with radio buttons. I want to make the PHP code display the total for the user when they submit the code.

Below is the code I have so far along with the prices for each item that would be in the store.

```
<?php 

$keybored = $_POST["keybored"];
$mouse = $_POST["mouse"];
$harddrive = $_POST["harddrive"];
$desktop = $_POST["desktop"];





$keyboredprice = 5.00;
$mouseprice =  3.50;
$hardriveprice = 20.00;
$desktopprice = 100;



$total = $prices;

echo "$total";


 ?>
```

The HTML code I'm working with is posted below that is for the webstore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <style>
        body {background-color: lightblue;}
        h1   {color: gray;}
            h2 {color: white;
        
            border-size: 1;
            width: 200px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 10px;}
            p  {color: white;
            font-size: 200%;}
            img {width:350px;height:300px;}
            
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="purchase.php" method="post">
<h1> Welcome to computer parts store</h1>
<h2>Keybored</h1>
<img src="keybored.jpg">
<p> Select how many <br>
<input type="radio" name="keybored" value="1"">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="keybored" value="2">2<br>
<input type="radio" name="keybored" value="3"> 3<br> <br>
</p>

<h2>Mouse</h1>
<img src="mouse.jpg">
<p> Select how many <br>
<input type="radio" name="mouse" value="1"">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="mouse" value="2">2<br>
<input type="radio" name="mouse" value="3"> 3<br> <br>
</p>

<h2>HarDrive</h1>
<img src="harddrive.jpeg" >
<p> Select how many <br>
<input type="radio" name="harddrive" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="harddrive" value="2">2<br>
<input type="radio" name="harddrive" value="3"> 3<br> <br>
</p>

<h2>Desktop</h1>
<img src="Desktop.jpg">
<p> Select how many <br>
<input type="radio" name="desktop" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="desktop" value="2">2<br>
<input type="radio" name="desktop" value="3"> 3<br> <br>
</p>


<p>
   First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
       Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
        Card type: <input type="text" name="type" > <br>
       Card Number: <input type="text" name="Card" > <br>
       Expiration date: <input type="text" name="exp" > <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit order"><br>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question about? You didn't say. You should post the HTML / form for this, or how/where you're getting your data from. Your question is unclear.

Comment: The code has been updated to display the HTML forum from where the data is coming from

Comment: Is this really your design?  Why are you limiting people to choosing 1-3 of an item?  That is literally not a design used by anyone.  People should be able to just type an integer into a box, with perhaps up and down arrows to increase or decrease the amount.  Default the number to 0.

Comment: This is a testing design it will be improved over time. I first need to figure out how to get the basics of it working. At some point, I will add up and down arrows to increase the number of items over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:  quantity * price.

```
<?php 

$keybored = $_POST["keybored"] ?? 0;
$mouse = $_POST["mouse"] ?? 0;
$harddrive = $_POST["harddrive"] ?? 0;
$desktop = $_POST["desktop"] ?? 0;

$keyboredprice = 5.00;
$mouseprice =  3.50;
$hardriveprice = 20.00;
$desktopprice = 100;

$total = ($keybored * $keyboredprice) + ($mouse * $mouseprice) + ($hardrive * $hardriveprice) + ($desktop * $desktopprice);

echo "$total";
```

PHP is loosely typed and will convert the form quantity strings to integers for you, and will also retain the floating point prices in the multiplication.

This uses the php7 null coalescing operator (??) to set the default quantity to 0 if any of the form elements are not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the price before you try to show its value to the user.
`$price = $keyboredprice + $mouseprice + $hardriveprice + $desktopprice;
$total = $price
echo "$total"`

Comment: That did not work all what that did was give the total price for all the items. Not for only the items the user selects on the page. If the user had selected no items it should end up showing 0 not 128.5